# Calculate sum with binom. coef.

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I'd like to get a closed form(i.e. formula) for this sum: $$ 2^{-n}\sum_{k=0}^{n}{k \dbinom{n}{\frac{n+k}{2}}},$$ where $\dbinom{n}{\frac{n+k}{2}} = 0$ if $\frac{n+k}{2}$ is not integer. How to do it if it's possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We consider the even case $2n$. The odd case can be done similarly.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{{k=0}\atop{k\equiv 0(2)}}^{2n}}&\color{blue}{k\binom{2n}{n+\frac{k}{2}}}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n2k\binom{2n}{n+k}\tag{1}\\
> &=2\sum_{k=0}^n(n+k)\binom{2n}{n+k}-2n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n}{n+k}\tag{2}\\
> &=4n\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{2n-1}{n+k-1}-2n\left(2^{2n-1}+\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=4n\left(2^{2n-1}+\binom{2n-1}{n-1}\right)-n2^{2n}-n\binom{2n}{n}\tag{4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=n\binom{2n}{n}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we replace $k$ with $2k$.
- In (2) we rearrange the sum as preparation for the next step.
- In (3) we apply $\binom{p}{q}=\frac{p}{q}\binom{p-1}{q-1}$ to the left-hand sum and simplify the right hand sum.
- In (4) we simplify the left-hand sum.